# Changing provisioning profile after replacing rejected binary?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

So my first official application got rejected as it was crashing on iOS 4.0 for which my application was not even made for (I didn't even check the option for iOS 4 tested). Now after resolving the bug I need to upload my application to the store. Should I create a new APP ID and a new distribution profile or just a new distribution provisioning profile for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the same ID, the same profile. Nothing to change at all. Just fix the bug and upload again.